# Polar chart usercontrol does not scale correctly and does not update in winforms, what is my error?

Tags: c#

First of all I don't use Microsoft's chart control, I use the graphics object, when I change the maximum radius it doesn't coincide with the circle of the radius in the chart, the degrees are fine, that is, they are drawn correctly, the problem is in the scale of the graph which does not match the calculated radius. Check the suggested questions but I didn't find any solution that solves the problem, I source code in c#.
I can't see where the error is!!. Attached what I have so far.

```
    private int compensar = 5;
    private float anguloDePAso = 30;
    private EnumDirAngulo anguloDireccion = EnumDirAngulo.AntiHorario;
    private float radioMin = 0;
    private float radioMax = 1;
    private int nroMarcas = 4;
    private Font marcaFuente = new Font("Arial", 6, FontStyle.Regular);
    private Color marcaColorFuente = Color.Green;
    private Color radioColor = Color.Blue;
    private float radioEspesor = 1f;
    private DashStyle radioPatron = DashStyle.Dot;
    private Color anguloColor = Color.DarkGray;
    private float anguloEspesor = 1f;
    private DashStyle anguloPatron = DashStyle.Dash;

    private Rectangle plotArea;

    private float xLimMin = 0f;
    private float xLimMax = 10f;
    private float yLimMin = 0f;
    private float yLimMax = 10f;

    private double pnlCX;
    private double pnlCY;
    private int polarGrados;
    private int polarRadio;
    private int polarAmplitud;
    private double pX;
    private double pY;

    private double x1;
    private double y1;
   

    public int PolarGrados
    {
        get { return polarGrados; }
        set { polarGrados = value; Invalidate(); }
    }
    public int PolarRadio
    {
        get { return polarRadio; }
        set { polarRadio = value; Invalidate(); }
    }
    public int PolarAmplitud
    {
        get { return polarAmplitud; }
        set { polarAmplitud = value; Invalidate(); }
    }
    public double EjeAbcisasX
    {
        get { return pX; }
        set {  Invalidate(); }
    }
    public double EjeOrdenadasY
    {
        get { return pY; }
        set { Invalidate(); }
    }
    public EnumDirAngulo AnguloDireccion
    {
        get { return anguloDireccion; }
        set { anguloDireccion = value; Invalidate(); }
    }
    public Color MarcaColorFuente
    {
        get { return marcaColorFuente; }
        set { marcaColorFuente = value; Invalidate(); }
    }
    public Font MarcaFuente
    {
        get { return marcaFuente; }
        set { marcaFuente = value; Invalidate(); }
    }
    public DashStyle PatronAngulo
    {
        get { return anguloPatron; }
        set { anguloPatron = value; Invalidate(); }
    }
    public float AnguloEspesor
    {
        get { return anguloEspesor; }
        set { anguloEspesor = value; Invalidate(); }
    }
    public Color AnguloColor
    {
        get { return anguloColor; }
        set { anguloColor = value; Invalidate(); }
    }
    public DashStyle RadioPatron
    {
        get { return radioPatron; }
        set { radioPatron = value; Invalidate(); }
    }
    public float RadioEspesor
    {
        get { return radioEspesor; }
        set { radioEspesor = value; Invalidate(); }
    }
    public Color RadioColor
    {
        get { return radioColor; }
        set { radioColor = value; Invalidate(); }
    }
    public int NroMarcas
    {
        get { return nroMarcas; }
        set { nroMarcas = value; Invalidate(); }
    }
    public float RadioMax
    {
        get { return radioMax; }
        set { radioMax = value; Invalidate(); }
    }
    public float RadioMin
    {
        get { return radioMin; }
        set { radioMin = value; Invalidate(); }
    }
    public float AnguloDePaso
    {
        get { return anguloDePAso; }
        set { anguloDePAso = value; Invalidate(); }
    }
    public int Compensar
    {
        get { return compensar; }
        set { Invalidate(); }
    }
    public enum EnumDirAngulo
    {
        AntiHorario = 0,
        Horario = 1
    }

    public GraficoPolar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pnlCX = panel1.Width / 2;
        pnlCY = panel1.Height / 2;

        SetPolarArea();
        
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        pnlCX = panel1.Width / 2;
        pnlCY = panel1.Height / 2;

        Graphics g = e.Graphics;

        EstableceEjePolar(g);

        DibujarGrados();
    }

    public Rectangle SetPolarArea()
    {
        Compensar = panel1.Width / 10;
        int height = panel1.Height - 2 * Compensar;
        int width = height;
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Compensar, Compensar, width, height);
        return rect;
    }
    public void EstableceEjePolar(Graphics g)
    {
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        Pen lapizEje = new Pen(AnguloColor, AnguloEspesor);
        SolidBrush pincelEje = new SolidBrush(MarcaColorFuente);
        StringFormat sFormat = new StringFormat();
        Rectangle rect = SetPolarArea();
        float xc = rect.X + rect.Width / 2;
        float yc = rect.Y + rect.Height / 2;
        // Dibujar circulos:
        float dr = RadioNormalizado(RadioMax / NroMarcas) - RadioNormalizado(RadioMin / nroMarcas);
        lapizEje.DashStyle = PatronAngulo;
        for (int i = 0; i < NroMarcas; i++)
        {
            RectangleF rect1 = new RectangleF(xc - (i + 1) * dr, yc - (i + 1) * dr,
                                               2 * (i + 1) * dr, 2 * (i + 1) * dr);
            g.DrawEllipse(lapizEje, rect1);
        }
        // Dibujar radios:
        lapizEje = new Pen(RadioColor, RadioEspesor);
        lapizEje.DashStyle = RadioPatron;
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)360 / AnguloDePaso; i++)
        {
            float x = RadioNormalizado(RadioMax) * (float)Math.Cos(i * AnguloDePaso * Math.PI / 180) + xc;
            float y = RadioNormalizado(RadioMax) * (float)Math.Sin(i * AnguloDePaso * Math.PI / 180) + yc;
            g.DrawLine(lapizEje, xc, yc, x, y);
        }
        // Dibujar las etiquetas de polarRadio:
        for (int i = 1; i <= nroMarcas; i++)
        {
            float rlabel = RadioMin + i * (RadioMax - RadioMin) / NroMarcas;
            sFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
            g.DrawString(rlabel.ToString(), MarcaFuente, pincelEje, new PointF(xc, yc - i * dr + 5), sFormat);
        }
        // Dibujar las etiquetas de los ángulos:
        SizeF MarcaTamañoFuente = g.MeasureString("A", MarcaFuente);
        float anguloEtiqueta = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)360 / AnguloDePaso; i++)
        {
            if (AnguloDireccion == EnumDirAngulo.Horario)
            {
                anguloEtiqueta = i * AnguloDePaso;
            }
            else if (AnguloDireccion == EnumDirAngulo.AntiHorario)
            {
                anguloEtiqueta = 360 - i * AnguloDePaso;
                if (i == 0)
                    anguloEtiqueta = 0;
            }
            sFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            float x = (RadioNormalizado(RadioMax) + 1.2f * MarcaTamañoFuente.Width) * (float)Math.Cos(i * AnguloDePaso * Math.PI / 180) + xc;
            float y = (RadioNormalizado(RadioMax) + 1.2f * MarcaTamañoFuente.Width) * (float)Math.Sin(i * AnguloDePaso * Math.PI / 180) + yc;
            g.DrawString(anguloEtiqueta.ToString(), MarcaFuente, pincelEje, new PointF(x, y - MarcaTamañoFuente.Height / 2), sFormat);
        }

    }
    //-- Dibujar angulo, polarRadio y el punto correspondiente -----------------------------------------
    private void DibujarGrados()
    {
        Rectangle rect = SetPolarArea();
        float xc = rect.X + rect.Width / 2;
        float yc = rect.Y + rect.Height / 2;
        float x = RadioNormalizado(RadioMax) * (float)Math.Cos(polarGrados * AnguloDePaso * Math.PI / 180) + xc;
        float y = RadioNormalizado(RadioMax) * (float)Math.Sin(polarGrados * AnguloDePaso * Math.PI / 180) + yc;


        if (polarGrados >= 0 && polarGrados <= 90)
        {
            pX = Math.Round(xc + (polarRadio * Math.Cos(polarGrados / (180 / Math.PI))), 2);
            pY = Math.Round(yc - (polarRadio * Math.Sin(polarGrados / (180 / Math.PI))), 2);
        }
        else if (polarGrados >= 91 && polarGrados <= 180)
        {
            pX = Math.Round(xc - (-polarRadio * Math.Cos(polarGrados / (180 / Math.PI))), 2);
            pY = Math.Round(yc + (-polarRadio * Math.Sin(polarGrados / (180 / Math.PI))), 2);
        }
        else if (polarGrados >= 181 && polarGrados <= 270)
        {
            pX = Math.Round(xc + (polarRadio * Math.Cos(polarGrados / (180 / Math.PI))), 2);
            pY = Math.Round(yc - (polarRadio * Math.Sin(polarGrados / (180 / Math.PI))), 2);
        }
        else if (polarGrados >= 271 && polarGrados <= 360)
        {
            pX = Math.Round(xc + (polarRadio * Math.Cos(polarGrados / (180 / Math.PI))), 2);
            pY = Math.Round(yc - (polarRadio * Math.Sin(polarGrados / (180 / Math.PI))), 2);
        }
        EjeAbcisasX = xc;
        EjeOrdenadasY = yc;
        DibujarPunto((float)pX, (float)pY, (float)polarAmplitud, 10, 2, Color.Blue, Color.Red);
        DibujarLine(xc, yc, (float)pX, (float)pY);
    }
    private void DibujarLine(double cenX, double cenY, float posX, float posY)
    {
        using (Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics())
        {
            g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0));
            g.DrawLine(pen, (float)cenX, (float)cenY, posX, posY);
        }
    }
    private void DibujarPunto(float posX, float posY, float PolarAmplitud,
                              float anguloDesdeElCentro, float diametroDelPunto,
                              Color ColorPunto, Color ColorCirculo)
    {
        PointF center = new PointF(posX, posY);
        float x = (center.X - diametroDelPunto);
        float y = (center.Y - diametroDelPunto);
        float ancho = 2 * diametroDelPunto;
        float alto = 2 * diametroDelPunto;

        using (Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics())
        {
            g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(ColorCirculo, 2), x - (PolarAmplitud / 2) + 2,
                                                    y - (PolarAmplitud / 2) + 2, 
                                                    PolarAmplitud, 
                                                    PolarAmplitud);
            g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(ColorPunto, 2),
                                                    x,
                                                    y, ancho, alto);
        }
    }
    public float RadioNormalizado(float r)
    {
        float radioNormalizado = new float();
        Rectangle rect = SetPolarArea();
        if (r < RadioMin || r > RadioMax)
        {
            r = Single.NaN;
        }
        radioNormalizado = (r - RadioMin) * rect.Width / 2 / (RadioMax - RadioMin);
        return radioNormalizado;
    }

    public Rectangle EstablecerPieArea()
    {
        Compensar = panel1.Width / 10;
        int height = panel1.Height - 2 * Compensar;
        int width = height;
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Compensar,
        Compensar, width, height);
        return rect;
    }

    public PointF Point2D(PointF pt)
    {
        PointF aPoint = new PointF();
        if (pt.X < xLimMin || pt.X > xLimMax || pt.Y < yLimMin || pt.Y > yLimMax)
        {
            pt.X = Single.NaN;
            pt.Y = Single.NaN;
        }
        aPoint.X = plotArea.X + (pt.X - xLimMin) * plotArea.Width / (xLimMax - xLimMin);
        aPoint.Y = plotArea.Bottom - (pt.Y - yLimMin) * plotArea.Height / (yLimMax - yLimMin);
        return aPoint;
    }
}
```

Comment: Update: the attached code doesn't work when written inside a user control like now, but when written in a form it works fine.

Comment: The panel size needs to be changed.  The panel is clipping the charts.  The panel needs to be larger than the chart or the panel needs scroll bars added.